# How to create a Thread pool in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I want to create a thread pool in Kotlin. I have been searching for hours in the internet and I can not get a single example. Can anyone provide examples. thank you.

Comment: Use the standard ThreadPool as you do in your Java code.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
    val executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)

    for (i in 0..9) {
        val worker = Runnable { println("Hello this is thread " + i) }
        executor.execute(worker)
    }

    executor.shutdown()
    executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
    println("Finished all threads")
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the `while (!isTerminated)` loop after `.shutdown()` is called... right? At that point aren't they all guaranteed to be terminated. If they aren't, then there should be a less resource intensive way than a tight while loop.

Comment: You can use `awaitTermination` to wait for all tasks to terminate instead of using the tight while loop.