# Custom Thread Pool with Coroutine async construct

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, threadpool, kotlin-coroutines

I am using async construct to execute certain task in parallel.

```
ids.forEach { id -> val result = async { getResult(id) } }
```

I have 2 questions in this regard.

1. I believe default thread pool to execute these tasks in parallel would have max(1, CPUs -1) threads. Is this understanding correct?
2. I want to use custom thread pool instead.

```
val context = newFixedThreadPoolContext(15, "custom pool")
```

How can I pass this pool to the async construct.
Please advice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a Thread pool in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44081033/how-to-create-a-thread-pool-in-kotlin) there's also a thread on Kotlin discussions [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/coroutine-or-threadpool-for-non-wait-simple-task/12097)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default `async()` inherits a coroutine dispatcher from the context that invoked it. If you create a single threaded context and inside it call `async()` then it will run in the same single-threaded environment.

In some cases dispatcher may be unspecified, e.g. if you use `GlobalScope.async()`. In that case `Dispatchers.Default` is used. [Documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-default.html) says that:

> By default, the maximum number of threads used by this dispatcher is equal to the number of CPU cores, but is at least two.

Using `async()` with your own dispatcher is as simple as:

```
async(context) { getResult(id) }
```